# Compilation BBVTracker with Simplescalar

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, simulation

I have encountered some some problem in compilation Basic Block Vector(BBV), developped by UCSD univ(http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~calder/simpoint/simplescalar-bbv.htm), with Simplescalar.  Without BBV, i compiled simplescalar successfully.

After unzip BBVtracker, there are total three files: modified sim-fast.c, bbtracker.h and bbtracker.c. I copied all three files to simplesim-3.o directory, and then make config-pisa & make after i update Makefile:

1, append bbtracker.h to HDRS, bbtracker.c to SRCS, bbv.$(OEXT) to $OBJS

2, Add bbv.o label at the end of Makefile.

```
SRCS =  main.c sim-fast.c sim-safe.c sim-cache.c sim-profile.c \
        sim-eio.c sim-bpred.c sim-cheetah.c sim-outorder.c \
        memory.c regs.c cache.c bpred.c ptrace.c eventq.c \
        resource.c endian.c dlite.c symbol.c eval.c options.c range.c \
        eio.c stats.c endian.c misc.c bbtracker.c \
        target-pisa/pisa.c target-pisa/loader.c target-pisa/syscall.c \
        target-pisa/symbol.c \
        target-alpha/alpha.c target-alpha/loader.c target-alpha/syscall.c \
        target-alpha/symbol.c

HDRS =  syscall.h memory.h regs.h sim.h loader.h cache.h bpred.h ptrace.h \
        eventq.h resource.h endian.h dlite.h symbol.h eval.h bitmap.h \
        eio.h range.h version.h endian.h misc.h bbtracker.h \
        target-pisa/pisa.h target-pisa/pisabig.h target-pisa/pisalittle.h \
        target-pisa/pisa.def target-pisa/ecoff.h \
        target-alpha/alpha.h target-alpha/alpha.def target-alpha/ecoff.h

#
# common objects
#
OBJS =  main.$(OEXT) syscall.$(OEXT) memory.$(OEXT) regs.$(OEXT) \
        loader.$(OEXT) endian.$(OEXT) dlite.$(OEXT) symbol.$(OEXT) \
        eval.$(OEXT) options.$(OEXT) stats.$(OEXT) eio.$(OEXT) \
        range.$(OEXT) misc.$(OEXT) machine.$(OEXT) bbv.$(OEXT)

.c.$(OEXT):                       # I dnot understand this LABEL. 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.c
bbv.$(OEXT): host.h misc.h machine.h machine.def endian.h version.h dlite.h bbtracker.h
main.$(OEXT): host.h misc.h machine.h machine.def endian.h version.h dlite.h
main.$(OEXT): regs.h memory.h options.h stats.h eval.h loader.h sim.h
```

After running make, the errors:

```
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/simplescalar/simplesim-3.0/libexo'
    gcc -o sim-fast `./sysprobe -flags` -DDEBUG -O0 -g -Wall   sim-fast.o main.o syscall.o memory.o regs.o loader.o endian.o dlite.o symbol.o eval.o options.o stats.o eio.o range.o misc.o machine.o bbv.o libexo/libexo.a `./sysprobe -libs` -lm
    gcc: error: bbv.o: No such file or directory
    make: *** [sim-fast] Error 1
```

Clearly, the bbv.o is not generated. It seems the way i add bbv.o is the same as other object files like main.o, range.o.

**[UPDATE]**
There is sample Makefile. 
https://svn.ece.gatech.edu/repos/Manifold/tags/0.4/code/models/processor/zesto/Makefile

After google the makedepend target, I updated with below:

```
OBJS =  main.$(OEXT) syscall.$(OEXT) memory.$(OEXT) regs.$(OEXT) \
        loader.$(OEXT) endian.$(OEXT) dlite.$(OEXT) symbol.$(OEXT) \
        eval.$(OEXT) options.$(OEXT) stats.$(OEXT) eio.$(OEXT) \
        range.$(OEXT) misc.$(OEXT) machine.$(OEXT) bbtracker.$(OEXT)

bbtracker.$(OEXT): /usr/include/stdlib.h  /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/malloc.h
bbtracker.$(OEXT): bbtracker.h
main.$(OEXT): host.h misc.h machine.h machine.def endian.h version.h dlite.h
main.$(OEXT): regs.h memory.h options.h stats.h eval.h loader.h sim.h
sim-fast.$(OEXT): bbtracker.h
```

The compilation successes now.